# Pandoc doesn't recognize documented '--defaults' option

Tags: pandoc

I use Pandoc as a static site generator and previous versions of the program allowed me to specify YAML files with metadata about the document like so:

```
pandoc --defaults ./base.yaml -o ./res/head.html ./res/head.md
```

However, now when I install it to a new system I get the following as output:

```
Unknown option --defaults.
```

The [Pandoc user guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#default-files) still specifies a --defaults option, but pandoc --help does not list the option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually caused by an outdated pandoc version. The `--defaults` option was added in pandoc 2.8, which was released about a year ago (2019-11-22). If you installed pandoc through your package manager, try to download it directly from the [releases](https://pandoc.org/releases.html) page, or use a [Docker image](https://github.com/pandoc/dockerfiles).